# .change doesn't work, when the value changes via another script

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, uislider

i have a select tag

`<select name="valueAA" id="valueAA">`

i use [UI Slider](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/), and i need to write a function onchange of select tag, but when it changes via slider, my function doesn't work.

```
$("#valueAA").change(function()
        {
            alert("works");// doesn't work
        })
```

can i avoid such behavior without changing the `ui slider` script, and what is the explanation of such behavior?

Thanks

UPDATE

the script looks like this

```
    $(function(){
                $('select#valueAA, select#valueBB').selectToUISlider({
                    labels:6

                });
     });
```

where i must put thise script? (i've tried many variant:))

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "slidechange", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, UI Slider is written on top of [jQuery UI's slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/).  The jQuery UI slider has events that you can tap into, *start*, *slide*, *change* and *stop*.  Using the example from the docs, you could try:

```
// Bind to the change event by type: slidechange.  
$("#valueAA").bind( "slidechange", function(event, ui) {
  $(this).change();
});
```

OR, using your updated example, supply a callback in the options for the slider:

```
$(function(){
            $('select#valueAA, select#valueBB').selectToUISlider({
                labels:6,
                change: function (event, ui) { $(this).change(); }
            });
 });
```

Comment: where i must put it? doesn't work when i put it in the main function:/

Comment: @Syom: Make sure you have the selector right, and make sure the slider is initalized **first**.  You could also supply it as an option to the initialization function - I've updated my example to show both methods.

Comment: It doesn't work because the change option you're passing must be inside sliderOptions: $('select#valueAA, select#valueBB').selectToUISlider({
  labels:6,
  sliderOptions: {
    change: function (event, ui) { $(this).change(); }
  }
});

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for a while but found the answer to be this:

```
$('.slider').selectToUISlider({ 
    sliderOptions: { 
        change:function() { 
            alert("works");
        } 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The select is being changed via the control itself, so the change event isnt being triggered. You should try to bind the change event on the ui slider and use the following code to trigger the change event on the select.

```
$("#valueAA").trigger("change");
```

Comment: is it impossible to do without changing their script?

Comment: You are not changing the script. Just combine my code with Andy's code and paste it under the selectToUISlider().